# AJAX - is order of execution guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, ajax

In the following code, is `doThisFirst()` guaranteed to execute before `doThisSecond()`?

```
var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : 
    new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        doThisSecond(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/myscript.php?", true);
xmlhttp.send();
doThisFirst();
```

If not, how can I guarantee this execution order (aside from the naive solution of setting a flag at the end of `doThisFirst()` and then polling `while(!flag);` before executing `doThisSecond()`)?.  I'm looking for a pure-Javascript solution (no jquery).

Important note: I do *not* want to execute the AJAX request synchronously, which would execute `doThisSecond()` before `doThisFirst()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doThisFirst()` will execute synchronously after `xmlhttp.send`, and `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` cannot be executed until the control flow has released back to the ["Event Loop"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop).

---

There is one catch. It *may* be possible* that the callback is executed as part of `.send()`, in which case `doThisSecond` would be executed first because the code never needed to release to the event loop. If you need to enforce an asynchronous behavior, simply wrapping `doThisSecond` as `setTimeout(function () { doThisSecond(xmlhttp.response.Text) }, 1)` will enforce that the function can not be called until the flow control is released to the event loop.

In your example it shouldn't make a difference, as I'm fairly certain that `onreadystatechange` is always called after the release to the event loop (synchronous XHR notwithstanding).

<sub>* whether by set to execute the AJAX call in a synchronous blocking manner, or due to caching, I honestly don't know enough of the XHR nuances cross-browser</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Does the number of messages sent to the event loop depend on the number of function calls or statements?  For instance, if I put 10 statements after `doThisFirst()`, will they all execute before `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: @1'', the messages in the event loop are determined by the type of message, not the quantity. Event listeners and callbacks using `setTimeout` are the most common ways of queueing more calls in the event loop. In this case `onreadystatechange` is an event listener.

Comment: This is my intuition as well, but I am trying to find documentation to support this. I've always wondered what happens when the content is cached.  It is possible, I suppose, that `send()` could fire the `onreadystatechange` event.  Do you know of documentation that requires that browsers respect the async nature of the `send()`?  Or are you relying on existing implementation of the browsers?

Comment: @BrianGenisio, I don't know if [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) enforces the asynchronous nature of those event callbacks. More importantly, I don't know enough about the existing implementation to warn in the case of possible cross-browser inconsistencies. It's why I added the second bit about using `setTimeout` to enforce that the callback code enters the event loop.

Comment: @zzzzBov I see your update.  I think that clarifies your response a bit.  The OP is asking if it is guaranteed.  I can't find any spec that defines the behavior, so I think the answer is "Not guaranteed, but practical."  I like your idea of enforcing the behavior, though there could still be subtile differences (I can't come up with any offhand).